# Varnish Cache - Sometime Hit and sometime Miss on the same page

Tags: caching, proxies

It's from the same page.  When I first load the page, it's "MISS" if I refresh the page it will "HIT"

If I go back to my website home page and come back to the same page again it's "MISS"  I refresh the page and its "HIT"

Do you know why varnish is behave like that?
I'm using varnish 3

Thanks for your help guys.

**HIT**

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Age:61
Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 18 Oct 2017 01:14:40 GMT
Etag:"1508289218-0"
Last-Modified:Wed, 18 Oct 2017 01:13:38 GMT
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Via:1.1 varnish
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Drupal-Cache:MISS
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Generator:Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
X-UA-Compatible:IE=edge,chrome=1
X-Varnish:83548823 83548200
X-Varnish-Cache:HIT
```

**MISS**

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Age:0
Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:22462
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 18 Oct 2017 01:13:39 GMT
Etag:"1508289218-0"
Last-Modified:Wed, 18 Oct 2017 01:13:38 GMT
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Via:1.1 varnish
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Drupal-Cache:MISS
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Generator:Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
X-UA-Compatible:IE=edge,chrome=1
X-Varnish:83548200
X-Varnish-Cache:MISS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe really looks like cache expiration. Note that the default TTL for cache in Varnish is 120 seconds only.

You would need to [adjust Varnish TTL](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/varnish/varnish-default-ttl) to something higher, obviously.

Comment: Yes you right, I've now changed the TTL from 120 sec to 52w  and it fixed the problem.   Thanks so much Daniel V.  Much appreciated your help.